# My alt+tab just showed only terminal windows -- what did I press?

Tags: linux-mint, alt-tab

I'm using Linux Mint 17.3 with Cinnamon.  I have a few applications open on the current workspace and was busy tabbing through them to get to a particular terminal window.  I think I accidentally pressed something near the tab key because suddenly I was only tabbing through terminal windows!  It was a pleasant surprise.  I think I'd got to a terminal window, paused to see if it was the one I wanted, and then tried to alt+tab to the next but (as I said) pressed something else.  I've been unable to replicate it and can't find it listed as a keyboard shortcut anywhere.  Anyone know what I must have pressed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (just above Tab). As far as I know it works generally with Gnome.

There are (probably) [all the shortcuts in Cinnamon](https://www.shortcutworld.com/en/linux/Linux-Mint-Cinnamon-Edition_17.2.html#link_3). Including yours:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>: Cycle through open windows of the same application on ANY Workspace

Comment: Thank you!  I actually did try that key combination, but I didn't release Alt first; in that case it behaves the same as Alt+Tab.